# get steps from fitbit array with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fitbit

using php I'm getting the most recent activity from fitbit, the info is then encoded as json from my angular application $json = json_encode($data);

this is returned,

```
"activities":[],"goals":{"activeMinutes":30,"caloriesOut":2184,"distance":8.05,"floors":10,"steps":10000},"summary":{"activeScore":-1,"activityCalories":55,"caloriesBMR":1728,"caloriesOut":1771,"distances":[{"activity":"total","distance":0.17},{"activity":"tracker","distance":0.17},{"activity":"loggedActivities","distance":0},{"activity":"veryActive","distance":0},{"activity":"moderatelyActive","distance":0},{"activity":"lightlyActive","distance":0.17},{"activity":"sedentaryActive","distance":0}],"elevation":0,"fairlyActiveMinutes":0,"floors":0,"lightlyActiveMinutes":17,"marginalCalories":22,"sedentaryMinutes":1380,"steps":238,"veryActiveMinutes":0}}
```

I want to get the "steps":238 from this array, nothing I've tried works...

in angular is use

```
$scope.data= angular.fromJson(response);
$scope.steps = $scope.data.summary.steps
```

I'm getting undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Unfortunately I'm at a hackathon with a few hours left to submit, so I don't have time to do more research and prevent down votes.

Comment: you shouldn't need to use `fromJson()` under most circumstances, but I think I would question that stray `1` at the beginning of your data, is that actually there in the real output?

Comment: yeah that's in the real output, don't know where it's coming from

Comment: if not from angular.fromJson what should I use?

Comment: angular already parses JSON automatically into an object with the `$http` service. however, that stray `1` isn't right; you need to figure that out first.

Comment: actually no it's not, I had $data['success']=true that's why it's there

Comment: either way, `response.data` should already be an object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78641/discussion-between-user2320607-and-claies).

Comment: Which PHP SDK you have used for getting fitbit data I tried with their official PHP and one given on the github but they didn't worked well... I need activities data.